# how to return objects straight after instantiating classes in python?

Tags: python, class

If I have these classes:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.version = version

class Builder:
    def __init__(self,version='0.0.1'):
        self.version = version

    def build(self):
        return MyObject(self.version)
```

is it possible to have the returned object by simply calling

```
versioned_obj = Builder('0.0.1') 
#instead of going through
builder = Builder('0.0.1')
versioned_object = builder.build()
```

?

have tried using `__init__()` but it must return `None`

Comment: `Builder('0.0.1').build()` would do the trick

Comment: or `self.version = MyObject(version)` in the init of builder

Comment: @CoryKramer your solution is the same as the one I posted, but on one line. I'm asking if it is possible to avoid calling .build() explicitely

Comment: why do you want to avoid this? Perhaps just make `Builder` a *function*, it doesn't look like you need a class.

Comment: Python isn't Java; not every function has to be a method of some class.

Comment: What is the purpose of `Builder` if all it's doing is giving a `version` to `MyObject`? In the real case scenario are there more attributes within `Builder` that relates to `MyObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be referring to is the `object.__new__` method. When you create an instance of a class, the `__new__` method is called to create and actually return the object that will be assigned, and then it's `__init__` method is called before assignment.

**example**

```
class otherclass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('hello from otherclass')

class myclass:
    # __new__ is a staticmethod by default so it recieves cls rather than self (no self exists yet..)
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('creating new instance of otherclass from myclass')
        return otherclass(*args, **kwargs)
```

calling `myclass()` prints:

```
creating new instance of otherclass from myclass 
hello from otherclass
Out[2]: <__main__.otherclass at 0x22192e0a898>
```

note: I didn't include it in the example, but `__init__` gets called with the same `*args, **kwargs` as `__new__`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, I get the example was not a real use case, but my question was really generic on how to achieve such a behaviour, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have a class, `MyObject`. If you want to instantiate `MyObject` in a single call, you don't need a builder at all, just initialize `MyObject` directly:

```
versioned_obj = MyObject('0.0.1')
```

Going back to what you asked, about using the `Builder` class without invoking `build()`: while it is possible to have the constructor of the builder class return a `MyObject` by overriding `__new__` I really don't recommend it.

Without understanding why you have a builder class (that seems to be doing nothing) it's harder to recommend alternatives, but there definitely are some. I can't recommend any of these based on the code you've shown, because they add complexity for no reason. But maybe they will give you an idea that will fit the code you haven't shown.

### Builder as Function

In the example above, there's no obvious reason why the builder needs to exist, let alone be a class, but if you wanted a builder and it didn't have to be a class, then it could simply be a function:

```
def build_myobj(version):
    return MyObject(version)

versioned_obj = build_myobj('0.0.1')
```

### Builder Factory Method

Or, if the Builder class is really suited to be a class and you just haven't shown us why, you could add a factory method to the builder:

```
class Builder:
    def __init__(self,version='0.0.1'):
        self.version = version

    def build(self):
        return MyObject(self.version)

    @staticmethod
    def factory(version):
        return Builder(version).build()

versioned_obj = Builder.factory('0.0.1')
```

### Function Using Builder

If you don't want to modify the builder class, but you want a single call:

```
def build_myobj(version):
    return Builder(version).build()

versioned_obj = build_myobj('0.0.1')
```

Comment: There are convoluted ways to achieve it, but it is of highly questionable value

Comment: In my specific case the builder is creating a DB entry and I would like to get back its object representation. This is not possible only through instantiation

Comment: So the builder is doing work that you haven't shown above, and you want to keep the builder?

Comment: If the `Builder` is a separate object that creates the DB entry and perhaps store some other information, how could you reasonably expect `Builder('0.0.1')` to return *both* the actual `Builder` object as well as `MyObject`? And if `Builder` only serves to perform some operation but not store any attributes, why not just have it as a `function` that returns the finished object instead of a `class`?

Comment: @Idlehands "how" is a tricky question, since overriding `__new__` totally *could* do exactly that. As juanpa rightly points out, though, its value is...doubtful.

Comment: @AdamSmith good point, though in my defence I did say "how can you *reasonably* expect" :)